# My Select tag's 1st option is not working but my other options works nicely

Tags: javascript, html, flask

I created a Select Field, so that when user clicks the options , it will send it to its respective page using `location.href` in js.

```
<select onchange="filter_category(this)" id="category">

   <option value="0">All</option>

       {% for cat in catg  %}
          <option  value={{cat.id}}>{{cat.name}} </option>
       {% endfor %}
                    
</select>
```

Javascript:

```
<script>
    function filter_category(elem){
        alert(elem)
        location.href="/market?id="+elem.selectedIndex + "&category=" + elem.selectedOptions[0].innerText
    }
</script>
```

The problem here is , that only **my 1st option** is **not working** according to my `filter_category()` function. When I click on 1st option in select field, **it does nothing**. But all my *other options are working properly* and transfer me to their respective page. I cant find why this is happening.

The **`alert`** function I added in the `filter_category()` function is also **not working** when I click my 1st option.

Comment: Why are you using `elem.selectedIndex` (which will be 0 for the first item) rather than `elem.selectedOptions[0].value` for the `id` parameter. They may be the same now, but in the future they may differ. For that matter, you could just use `elem.value` and it would give you the same value.

Comment: @Heretic Monkey but its still not solving my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing HTML did the trick as suggested by @Ezani.The first option was selected by default on every page refresh , so *onchange* function wasn't working on it.

Here is the code:

```
<select onchange="filter_category(this)" id="category">
<option value="none" selected disabled hidden> Select an Option </option>

<option value="0">All</option>

{% for cat in catg  %}
<option  value={{cat.id}}>{{cat.name}} </option>
{% endfor %}
                        
</select>
```

Comment: Yes! Good @puranjan!

Answer (score 1):

This is the offending line:

```
 <option value="0">All</option>
```

You've made this the first selection in your list of option selection and so it does not give you a valid Cat ID or Cat Name. You can perhaps exclude it from your options list.

Comment: The cat.id is supposed to be the value of that option field and cat.name is the text that is displayed.  I can't remove this field.